# Is information about a filesystem's bad blocks preserved after formatting a partition?

Tags: fsck, badblocks

I have a drive with bad blocks. The filesystem is aware of them, and I read that you can feed `e2fsck` with a `badblocks` repport to inform the file system that there are some bad blocks. (I think the option `-c` in `fsck` is doing the same thing.)

If I format the partition and get rid of the file system, so is all information about bad blocks lost? Need I inform the new file system about bad blocks? Or will the SMART system do so for me?

Thanks!

Comment: This might be more suited to [Unix.SE] considering it's not specifically about Ubuntu, but more about, well, [Unix.SE].

Comment: I'm surprised there's no answer for this on the first 5 pages of google.

Comment: Yes, I was looking around but did not find anything (or did not find the good key words to look for it...)

Comment: It looks like [this](https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/305475-where-is-the-information-stored-that-says-where-bad-sectors-are-located) is in the right *direction*.

Answer (score 2):

From the vast<sup>cough</sup> amount of research I've come across in the last five minutes, for instance [this](https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/305475-where-is-the-information-stored-that-says-where-bad-sectors-are-located) and [this](https://superuser.com/questions/61899/will-reformatting-my-hard-drive-fix-bad-sectors-on-it) (from [SU.SE](https://superuser.com)), it would *appear* that **device-wide metadata about bad blocks is stored in the Master Boot Record or GUID Partition Table** (the disk's partition table that starts at address `00000000: 0x00`).

It seems unlikely it would be stored in the partition's filesystem's table of contents. Anyways, the information will only go away if you write the disk a new *partition table*, which will **irreversably destroy all data** on the **entire disk**.

---

If you're using a disk that has bad blocks for anything remotely mission-ciritical (or even your own data), that disk is bound to fail irreparably in the near future, and it's cheaper and easier and safer to buy a new disk.

Comment: Thanks

The size of the MBR is only 512 bytes, and I checked the structure, i don't think there is space reserved for this purpose.

Comment: Well, there's nowhere else on the disk for them to be stored. It's possible Linux (perhaps `mount`, `fsck` or `udev` and the kernel) has a list of them somewhere for its own use, but that list is incidental.

Comment: From what I read (for example this: http://superuser.com/questions/600075/are-hard-disks-bad-sectors-filesystem-dependent), I think bad blocks are both stored in the file system and in the microcode (managed by SMART?) of the hard drive. So I guess if I format the hard drive, the new file system will not be aware of the bad blocks, but it's ok because SMART will not let the OS access them. However I did not find formal information about this, only people discutting about it on forums.

Comment: Also, I think the microcode of a hard drive can handle only a limited number of bad sectors, what happen after? Is the file system wil lbe able to manage them? I guess if you reach this point, better to change of hard drive as soon as possible.

And yes, I agree, when you start to have bad blocks, better to change of hard drive as soon as possible.